# Is there a way to eliminate the extra click my game currently requires to restart?

Tags: reactjs

This is a clicky game that requires you click each image once without clicking one twice.  Issue I'm having is with resetting the game after all images are clicked.  It works currently but requires you to click a random image after all 12 have been to render the console log (you win) and reset the game board.  I'm trying to eliminate that last click.

Started the issue not being able to render console.log (you win).  Removed code via trial an error to clean up my code and isolate where each piece is working.  I feel like the issue is with the handleClick function which I've tried to research and I haven't been able to come up with much as far as eliminating this extra click.  I don't feel like I know what I should necessarily be searching for to get on the right track.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        cards,
        score: 0,
        hiscore: 0,
        message: '',
        clicked: [],
    }
}

handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
        score: 0,
        hiscore: this.state.hiscore,
        message: '',
        clicked: [],
    })
    this.handleShuffle()
}

handleGuess = () => {
    let newScore = this.state.score + 1
    this.setState({
        score: newScore,
    })

    if (newScore >= this.state.hiscore) {
        this.setState({
            hiscore: newScore,
        })
    }
    this.handleShuffle()
}

handleClick = id => {
    if (this.state.clicked.indexOf(id) === -1) {
        this.setState({ clicked: this.state.clicked.concat(id) })
        this.handleGuess()
    } else if (this.state.clicked.length === 12) {
        let win = 'You Win'
        this.setState({
            message: win
        })
        console.log(win)
        this.handleReset()
    } else {
        let lose = 'You Lose'
        this.setState({
            message: lose
        })
        console.log(lose)
        this.handleReset()
    }
}
```

I want it to reset on after the 12th image is selected successfully.  It works but only if you click any random image after successfully clicking each image once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `componentDidUpdate()` which will execute whenever you update your component-state or props.

So when the user clicks the last and final-card, your component-state updates, and it triggers `componentDidUpdate()`

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  if(this.state.clicked.length == 12){
    console.log("You win")
    window.alert("You win")
    this.handleReset()
  }
}
```

So we define a condition inside it which will run if passed.

Also, to render an alert when your app starts, you can do something like:

```
componentDidMount(){
   window.alert("My instructions:")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome @TylerEdge! I hope this works. And if it does, please consider upvoting and marking this as the answer.

Comment: It resets my game.  I placed it above handle reset.  It doesn't render my console.log message now though.  I could just place those setState params in there though yeah?

Comment: I'm planning on using those messages for notification pop ups.

Comment: @TylerEdge Oh yeah! :) You can totally just do a console.log() in there. Here let's just do an alert for example.

Comment: Figured the rest out while I was waiting to hear back.  If I wanted to render an alert as soon as the page loads up with instructions for instance would I just use a different component function like the one you showed me?

Comment: Been racking my brains on the rest all day so seriously thanks for the help.  My teachers haven't even responded to me about it yet.  That last alert I wanted to implement as soon as the page loads is all I need now.  Its not a requirement but I thought it would be a cool idea!

Comment: @TylerEdge for sure bro. If you want to render the instructions in an alert or something you can use `componentDidMount()`. Here I'll show you in the solution above.

Comment: I did that too after you showed me the first solution.  I was hoping to have it render that after the page is there before any input though.  That does work though!  Just not exactly how I wanted to.  Trying to find a good reference for all this to add to my list of helpful material.

Comment: Hmmm, consider the react-docs. They're pretty legendary in my opinion. :) . https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html